# How to test if two Map objects are equal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface in typescript

```
export interface Customer {
    customerId: CustomerId;
    user: User;
    color?: string;
    test2: string;
    testMode?: DocumentMode;
    additionalData?: Map<string, string>;
}
```

I have the following function that checks to see if there's been a change in customer from the previous state

```
   private _hasChanged(newCustomers: Map<CustomerId, Customer>): boolean {
     for (const [newId, newCustomer] of newCustomers.entries()) {
        const customer = this._clients.get(newId);
        if (!customer || JSON.stringify(newCustomer) !== JSON.stringify(customer)) {
                    return true;
         }
     }
    
     return false;
  }
```

comparing works using JSON.Stringify but I noticed that when the additionalData is different from one customer to another, the function returns false, saying that the customers haven't changed.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Add a special case for the Map.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` isn't guaranteed to give the same results if the insertion order of properties on `obj` isn't known to be stable.  Could you remove that from the question so that it's not distracting?  If you want to know how to compare two `Map`s as equal you can still ask that.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will produce an empty object for a `Map`, so that is not the right tool. You'll have to iterate through the maps...